# Convert columns to rows without using pivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have been assigned to get the data in required format from two tables.

TableStaff :

```
STaffID | Staff Name
--------------------
1      | John 
2      | Jack
```

and TableLead

```
LeadID | LeadValue | LeadStaus | StaffID
----------------------------------------
  1    | 5000      | New       | 1
  2    | 8000      | Qualified | 1
  3    | 3000      | New       | 2
```

As you will notice **StaffID** is the **foreign key** to  **TableStaff**.

I have to represent the data in following format

```
StaffID | StaffName | NewLeadCount | QualifiedLeadCount 
-------------------------------------------------------
1       | John      |  1           |   1
2       | Jack      |  1           |   0
```

What I have tried:

```
SELECT 
    count([LeadID ]) as LdCount , 
    'New' as StageName  
FROM 
    [dbo].[TableLead] 
where 
    [LeadStaus] = 'New' 
UNION 
SELECT 
    count([LeadID ]) as LdCount , 
    'Qualified' as StageName 
FROM 
    [dbo].[TableLead] 
where 
    [LeadStaus] = 'Qualified '
```

Any NULL spots should be replaced by 0. Can anyone show me the right direction to approach the problem? Without using pivot (because of its restrictive nature).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a SUM(CASE... and a GROUP BY

```
SELECT
    TableLead.StaffID, 
    Staff.StaffName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TableLead.LeadStatus = 'New' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NewLeadAccount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TableLead.LeadStatus = 'Qualified' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) QualifiedLeadAccount
FROM
    TableLead
JOIN
    Staff
    ON Staff.StaffID = TableLead.StaffID
GROUP BY
    TableLead.StaffID,
    Staff.StaffName;
```

> ```
> StaffID | StaffName | NewLeadAccount | QualifiedLeadAccount
> ------: | :-------- | -------------: | -------------------:
>       1 | John      |              1 |                    1
>       2 | Jack      |              1 |                    0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e59cb59f1bc4de08902ed222e6c1d417)*

Comment: Thanks a lot Will there be any performance issues by using conditional aggregation when data size is huge?

Comment: It depends. Not in advance, but you must check it.